# BasicAuthenticationFilter is not getting called if authorization is not passed with header while making request

Tags: java, spring-security-rest

I am trying to authenticate each incoming HTTP request using JWT token. For that, I have implemented the `AuthenticationProvider interface(by overriding authenticate function)` provided by spring security. But the authenticate function is getting called only if we pass authorization parameters along with headers, else the request is getting processed without going in to authenticate function flow.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security intercepts the header with authorization parameter in it .

For more knowledge refer to [How authentication works](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-http-basic-authentication-works-in.html)